# Problem with "JQuery Adress Tabs", anchor tags not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I get this error, (Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href$=roomindex.php]) and the link to roomindex.php is outside the tab.
This error seems to be showing up every time there is a href or title attribute on an element inside a tab.

Does anyone know the cause for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an option "Enables the plugin for all the content links" which i disabled and that fixed it. Facepalm

Answer (score 0):

Quotes around the value?

```
  a[href$="roomindex.php"]
```

Comment: I assume the plugin does that. Because I don't.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but do you have jquery and jquery ui included?